Stability for an adaptive PD controller
I have an adaptive PD controller, of the form:
$$
\tau = K_p(\mathcal{L}) \; q_e \; + \; K_d(\mathcal{L}) \; \dot{q}_e
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the energy of the system. Even though the PD gains are not explicitly dependent on time, does this introduce time-dependence? I ask because this is important for the stability argument. If it does, how would I go about making stability arguments (Lyapunov or Passivity) for such an adaptive controller?
The resources I have been looking at for PD stability are:
Page 23, https://www3.nd.edu/~lemmon/courses/ee580/lectures/chapter10.pdf
Page 35, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-69255-3
